# Request-id in SNMP

Tags: snmp, oid

I am writing a function block in RTU so it gets an OID and gives the value. I have realised in Wireshark that every OID has its own request-id which is specific. I want to know if there is a special way to figure out the request-id without having to go through Wireshark.

Comment: “every OID has its own request-id which is specific”? What's that? An OID never contains something like request ID. They are different definitions with little relationship with each other. Find an SNMP book to study the concepts once again please. You can then go back and edit this question.

Comment: Or read the authoritative RFCs, eg. googling for a minute or 2 yields https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3416#section-4.1